# Php script is working on its own but not included in html

Tags: php, html

i am trying to use a php script in my html website. The php script is working as intended when I run it. My php script:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","demo","123abc");
mysql_select_db("demo");
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT vorname FROM users"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){ 
$select= '<select name="select">';   
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
      $select.='<option value='.$rs['vorname'].'>'.$rs['vorname'].'</option>'; 
  } 
} 
$select.='</select>'; 
echo $select;  
?>
```

Now what I want is, to have the dropdown on my website on different locations. My idea was to just insert the php script whenever I need it. My html part:

```
<td>
<?php include 'http://localhost/Testsamples/test.php'; ?>
</td>
```

But it is not working and I don't know why.
Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: The html file is in a different folder. Html= localhost/Prompt/index.html and then php= localhost/Testsamples/test.php

Comment: Apart from the answers below about the path, your php will probably not get executed if the including file has the `.html` extension. Change that to `.php` as well.

Comment: @jeroen it's possible to have HTML execute php, but it requires some adjustments in the system files. I have no clue on where he should look though, since I have no clue what local server he uses. However safer bet is indeed to just change `html` to `php`

Comment: @Dorvalla That's why I said `probably`. Modifying the OP's server settings is indeed a bit out of the scope of this question :-)

Comment: @jeroen your post was the solution in the end. Thanks a lot to all the help from everyone. =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't include the file by its URL, you must use the system filepath:

```
<td>
<?php include '/path/to/Testsamples/test.php'; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: I moved them in the same folder now. Its localhost/Prompt/test.php now. The html file is in the Prompt folder also. Do I just write /test.php as the path now?

Comment: You can do `./test.php` or `test.php`

Comment: @LittleMonstr Change `include` to `require`, the error message will tell you what path php is looking for.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on PHP should be telling you if it can't find that file.

Answer (score 3):

You can't include using URL (like http://www.domain.com/script.php).

Use relative path like :

```
<?php include "/path/test.php"; ?>
```

Use `require` is better than `include`, you will have a direct error if file is not found.

Comment: `"/path/test.php"` **is** an absolute path. What the OP had was a URL.

Comment: You should modify the wording a bit: As mentioned, the original path is a url and the path you are using is actually an absolute path.

Comment: You are right, I just named "absolute" too fast. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to include it from an absolute path you need to have `allow_url_include` enabled on your php.ini.

See here: http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_include.html

However, if your file is on the same system, you should use relative urls. i.e. `include 'testSamples/test.php` (or something similar). You could also use basic folder nav ( e.g. `../testSamples/test.php` or use an include relative to root: `/public_html/foo/bar/testSamples/test.php`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php /* At the first instance of call, to eliminate multiple opening of SQL connections for the smae data */
    ob_start();
    get_file_contents('http://localhost/Testsamples/test.php'); 
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
?>
<td>
    <?php echo $contents; ?>
</td>
```

*edit* - as pointed out in the other answers, you probably do not want to be including absolute paths!